# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow.python.eager'

Tags: python, tensorflow, eager

I installed Tensorflow packages but it gives an error like this:

[image]

I also upgraded tensorflow version in case:

[image]

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: This is showing from importing part   --> import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, MaxPool2D, Conv2D
import pickle


X = pickle.load(open('X_400_image','rb'))
y = pickle.load(open("Y_400_image", "rb"))

print(X[:5])

Comment: Looks like Tensorflow not installed properly. Please provide the Tensorflow version. Thanks!